# Xamarin not displaying text from TextCell

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

My view looks like this

```xml
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Guests}"
                                          Margin="0" HeightRequest="300"
                                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                          RowHeight="28"
                                          SelectionMode="None">
                                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextCell Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="{StaticResource BT-DarkGray}"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListView>
```

My model has Guest as property what is deserialized using newtonsoft, I had to add the JsonProperty tag on the property otherwise the setter was not called. the list for this test case contains 12 items.

```cs
private ObservableCollection<string> _guest;

        [JsonProperty("guests")]
        public ObservableCollection<string> Guests
        {
            get => _guest; 
            set => SetProperty(ref _guest, value); 
        }

        private ObservableCollection<LocalShowFlight> _flights;
        [JsonProperty("flights")]
        public ObservableCollection<LocalShowFlight> Flights
        {
            get => _flights; 
            set => SetProperty(ref _flights, value); 
        }
        private ObservableCollection<LocalShowTiming> _timings;
        [JsonProperty("timings")]
        public ObservableCollection<LocalShowTiming> Timings
        {
            get => _timings; 
            set => SetProperty(ref _timings, value); 
        }

        public void RaisCollectionChanged()
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Guests));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Flights));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TimingOther));
        }
```

My viewmodel has a Model property where i'm calling RaisCollectionChanged to make sure the on property changes is called.

```cs
public ShowBandAppModelV2 Model
        {
            get { return _model; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _model, value);
                Model?.RaisCollectionChanged();
            }
        }
```

the end result is showing
[image]

Why is the text not displayed since the cells are generated, now the strange thing is with hot reload when I remove the `.` in the binding and save the view the text appears en when I put the `.` back the texts changes, so I think it has to do with binding put I don't see what I'm missing. same thing when changing color, It looks like the view has no correct binding on first load.

Anyone with an idea on how to solve this, ore using a different view then listviews if it can solve the issue.

---

Found a fix, when I change the dataTemplete to viewcell with a label, the binding works.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                                            <ViewCell>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="{StaticResource BT-DarkGray}" VerticalTextAlignment="Start"
                                                       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                                            </ViewCell>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: are you **positive** that `Guests` contains valid data?  Have you tried changing the text color to black?  Or hardcoding a value instead of binding it?  That will tell you if the problem is the data or the UI

Comment: Please edit your question to fix typos. I find it hard to read.

Comment: *"My model has Guest as property"* - `Guest` is the string? Then tell Xamarin to use that: `<TextCell Text="{Binding Guest}" ...`.

Comment: You could set breakpoints to see if the text is right in the binding source, Guests.. Or you could share us more details if possible

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Guest is on ObservableCollection<string> property of the model

Comment: *"Found a fix ..."* FYI, When you find a solution, please do not add it to the question. Rather, "answer your own question" by adding "Your Answer" below these comments. This will help others who find this Q&A in the future to discover the answer faster. Thanks!